# How to populate without using mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to implement populate() function without using mongoose in the code below:

`

```
    course.students.forEach(async (student, i) => {
      const s = await Student.findById(student._id);

      console.log(s.toObject()); // gets student data properly

      course.students[i] = s; // does not work
    });

    console.log(course.json());
```

`

I just want to update the students array with the data fetched. Can anyone explain me with the assignation doesn't works?

Thank you all! :)

Comment: I think `s` here is a cursor. Need to use `findOne()` or get the results(s) you want from the cursor. Alternatively use `$lookup` to do all of this in the database and avoid a bunch of network round trips

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is not meant to be used with `await`, try to change to a `for` loop and use `lean()` to return a plain object from the query:

```
for (let i = 0; i < course.students.length; i++) {
  const student = course.students[i];
  course.students[i] = await Student.findById(student._id).lean();
}

console.log(course);
```